# Javascript Vue Event Emit Not Value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, emit

Good Evening,

does anyone know why the input toggle switch value is being flipped to the reverse value when emitted to the parent component?  I'm new to Vue, I have been working with it on and off for a few days now.  It works in concept, I can see the value of the attribute in both areas using vue dev tools.  However, the child value is reversed when emitted to the parent and assigned.  I could immediately fix by !'ing the incoming value, but I would like to find out if anyone knows why this is occurring.

Parent Update Bind

```
updateMiddle(article){
  this.article.meta_title = article.meta_title;
  this.article.meta_desc = article.meta_desc;
  this.article.published = article.published;
  this.article.is_review = article.is_review;
}
```

Child Emit

```
methods: {
  update() {
    this.$emit('changeMiddle',this.article)
  }
```

Input

```
<input id="tc-review" type="checkbox" hidden="hidden" name="is_review" 
       v-model="article.is_review" v-on:input="update">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the *input* event fires **before** the `v-model` binding has changed the data.

Simple solution is to use the *change* event instead. For example

```
<input v-model="article.is_review" @change="update">
```

Simplified demo ~ http://jsfiddle.net/u20h5tzv/

**Hint**: Try changing it back to `@input` and see the difference in timing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'll take the faster method.  However, I still experience the same issue.  I'm doing a hopefully temp resolution by flipping the incoming value.  I posted the entire code of the parent and child to see if its more helpful.

Comment: Never mind, you were correct.  I forgot to run NPM run watch to apply my code changes ><.  Thanks for the assist! =)